# J'étais tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j' (en) ai oublié de vous poser la question

Tags: prépositions

> J'étais tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'**en** ai oublié de vous
> poser la question.

Quel est le rôle du "en" dans cette phrase ?

Answer (score 2):

*En* fait référence à ce qui vient d'être dit (le fait que j'étais très concentrée). Il met donc l'emphase sur la cause de l'oubli.

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement je ne mettrais pas en dans cette phrase.
J’ai oublié de vous poser la question.

Par contre, je dirais : « j’en ai oublié la question » où « en » est complément du nom « question ».

Comment: Est-ce qu"on peut changer le placement du mot "en" et dire « J'étais tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'ai oublié de vous en poser la question?